# Vertical space depending on height of marginpar

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

I'd like to set a law text consisting of articles, marginal notes and, in most cases, paragraphs (`\abs`). The marginal notes should always start on the same line as the first line of the article text, be it a paragraph or not.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrbook}

\newcommand\mpar[1]{\marginpar{\flushleft\footnotesize #1}}
\newcommand{\art}[3]{\textbf{Art.\,#1}\\*[0.5ex]\mpar{#2}#3\par}
\newcommand{\abs}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1~}#2\\}
\newcommand{\absl}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1~}#2} % for last paragraphs

\begin{document}

\art{1}{marginpar for article~1}{%
\abs{1}{The first line of the article text should be on the same line as the corresponding marginpar.}
\absl{2}{So this article is how it should be.}
}

\art{2}{Very\\long\\marginpar\\for article~2}{%
This article is okay, too. But if the marginpar uses more vertical space than this text...}

\art{3}{incorrect marginpar}{%
\abs{1}{...then this article text is not on the same line with its corresponding marginpar anymore.}
\absl{2}{Another paragraph.}
}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use marginnote but there the notes just overlap. Then I tried to measure the height of the marginal note and set the article body in a box with that size but failed miserably. The measuring methods I found on this website and on the web in general are very hard to understand for a beginner like me.

But maybe that's not even the way to go. I also thought about using a tabular, but the document will be *twosided* and the *marginpars should always be on the outside of the page*. Maybe there is a way to switch the rows of a tabular depending on if it's on an odd or even page but I couldn't find a solution for this either.

Of course I could use a vspace between the articles but since it's going to be a very big document, I'd like to have the space adjusted automatically.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! You may have a look at [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for a quick intro if you wish to familiarize yourself with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of testing I found a solution that does what I want. It may not be very elegant, but it does the trick.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrbook}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\marginalie
\newlength\article
\newlength\difference

\newcommand{\art}[3]{
    \settototalheight\marginalie{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\footnotesize #2}}
    \settototalheight\article{\parbox{\textwidth}{#3}}
    \setlength{\difference}{\the\marginalie-\the\article}
    \textbf{Art.\,#1}\\*[0.5ex]\clubpenalty=10000\marginpar{\flushleft\footnotesize #2}#3\par
    \ifnum\difference>0 \vspace{\the\difference} \else \addvspace{1ex} \fi
}
\newcommand{\abs}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1~}#2\\}
\newcommand{\absl}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1~}#2} % for last paragraphs

\begin{document}

\art{1}{marginpar for article~1}{%
\abs{1}{The first line of the article text should be on the same line as the corresponding marginpar.}
\absl{2}{So this article is how it should be.}
}

\art{2}{Very\\long\\marginpar\\for article~2}{%
This article is okay, too. But if the marginpar uses more vertical space than this text...}

\art{3}{incorrect marginpar}{%
\abs{1}{...then this article text is not on the same line with its corresponding marginpar anymore.}
\absl{2}{Another paragraph.}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above is your original.  Below the "=====" is the proposed fix, achieved by redefining `\art`. [EDITED to fix left margin and raggedright in marginpar].  Note also that, by using `\tabular` as the proposed fix, that an article will not break midway across a page boundary.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrbook}

\newcommand\mpar[1]{\marginpar{\flushleft\footnotesize #1}}
\newcommand{\art}[3]{\textbf{Art.\,#1}\\*[0.5ex]\mpar{#2}#3\par}
\newcommand{\abs}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1~}#2\\}
\newcommand{\absl}[2]{\textsuperscript{#1~}#2} % for last paragraphs

\begin{document}

\art{1}{marginpar for article~1}{%
\abs{1}{The first line of the article text should be on the same line as the corresponding marginpar.}
\absl{2}{So this article is how it should be.}
}

\art{2}{Very\\long\\marginpar\\for article~2}{%
This article is okay, too. But if the marginpar uses more vertical space than this text...}

\art{3}{incorrect marginpar}{%
\abs{1}{...then this article text is not on the same line with its corresponding marginpar anymore.}
\absl{2}{Another paragraph.}
}

==========================================

\renewcommand\art[3]{%
\textbf{Art.\,#1\rule[-1ex]{0ex}{1ex}}\\
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{0ex}}ll}
\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{#3} & \parbox[t]{1in}{\raggedright\footnotesize#2}\\
\end{tabular}
}

\art{1}{marginpar for article~1}{%
\abs{1}{The first line of the article text should be on the same line as the corresponding marginpar.}
\absl{2}{So this article is how it should be.}
}

\art{2}{Very\\long\\marginpar\\for article~2}{%
This article is okay, too. But if the marginpar uses more vertical space than this text...}

\art{3}{incorrect marginpar}{%
\abs{1}{...then this article text is not on the same line with its corresponding marginpar anymore.}
\absl{2}{Another paragraph.}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some articles are very long. That they don't break midway unfortunately prevents your fix from solving my problem. Furthermore, it's going to be a twosided document and I'd like the marginpars – if possible – to be on the outside of a page. But with your fix they are always on the right side.