# Set a minimum height for biblatex entries

Tags: biblatex, spacing

Is there an option to fix a minimum height for entries other than redefining each bibliography driver with a `parbox` like described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319524/qrcode-in-bibliography-margin-bibliography-entry-with-height-of-marginpar-conten)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `begentry` and `finentry` bibmacros to wrap each entry in a fixed height `minipage`.

Because entries can be nested, we need to track the entry depth and only begin and end the `minipage` at the outer level.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newlength{\minbibdepth}
\setlength{\minbibdepth}{2cm}

\makeatletter
\newcount\@entrydepth
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \global\advance\@entrydepth\@ne
  \ifnum\@entrydepth>1\relax
  \else
    \begin{minipage}[t][\minbibdepth][t]{\linewidth}%
  \fi}
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \ifnum\@entrydepth=1\relax
    \end{minipage}%
  \fi
  \global\advance\@entrydepth-\@ne}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nocite{westfahl:space,bertram,doody}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]